# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BanGuayaPrototype.ViewController getTextId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe5f69027d0'

Tags: ios, swift3

Buenas tardes:
Soy un poco nuevo en el desarrollo de apps nativas para iOS, estoy trabajando en swift 4 y al intentar pasar a otra pantalla desde mi loggin, me esta generando el siguiente error:

> BanGuayaPrototype[11289:1143773] -[BanGuayaPrototype.ViewController getTextId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe5f69027d0
>   2018-01-10 14:40:06.213350-0500 BanGuayaPrototype[11289:1143773] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BanGuayaPrototype.ViewController getTextId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe5f69027d0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d42512b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108ce3f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4a6024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
>       3   UIKit                               0x0000000109a52f51 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3a7f78 ___forwarding_** + 1432
>       5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3a7958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       6   UIKit                               0x0000000109820972 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010999fc3c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010999ff59 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010a548407 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 155
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000109a52939 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 286
>       11  UIKit                               0x000000010a548026 -[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 48
>       12  UIKit                               0x0000000109a529e8 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 140
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010a547ef6 -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 135
>       14  UIKit                               0x00000001098d6463 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree] + 167
>       15  UIKit                               0x00000001098d6a73 **UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 72
>       16  UIKit                               0x00000001098d685d -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 95
>       17  UIKit                               0x000000010999b591 __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke.674 + 858
>       18  UIKit                               0x0000000109994b5b -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 111
>       19  UIKit                               0x0000000109c1cc1e -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 44
>       20  UIKit                               0x0000000109998f4f __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 183
>       21  UIKit                               0x000000010a58d088 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 102
>       22  UIKit                               0x0000000109991dba -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 251
>       23  UIKit                               0x0000000109991a31 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1397
>       24  UIKit                               0x00000001099940c8 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 104
>       25  UIKit                               0x00000001098b56c4 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 343
>       26  UIKit                               0x00000001098b5d23 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 293
>       27  UIKit                               0x00000001098b5dd7 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 473
>       28  QuartzCore                          0x00000001096696bd _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 323
>       29  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e54733d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       30  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e5525f9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 628
>       31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3e7e39 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9
>       32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3ac462 __CFRunLoopRun + 2402
>       33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3ab889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
>       34  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110ff39c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
>       35  UIKit                               0x000000010981f5d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       36  BanGuayaPrototype                   0x00000001083a31d7 main + 55
>       37  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e5c3d81 start + 1
>       38  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

A continuación tienen las clases implicadas:

```
ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var getText: UITextField!
var cliente = Cliente()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func onGoButtonLH(_ sender: Any) {
    let idTxt:String? = getText.text

    if idTxt == "1234" {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginToComercial", sender: self)
    }else{
        let urlString = "http://localhost:8080/RestServiceBgPrototype/cognitiva/clientService/"+idTxt!
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }
            //Implement JSON decoding and parsing
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                self.cliente = try! decoder.decode(Cliente.self, from: data)
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation{
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginToHome", sender: self.cliente)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "LoginToHome") {
        let homeViewController = segue.destination as? HomeViewController
        let cliente = sender as! Cliente
        homeViewController?.cliente = cliente
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}

HomeViewController.swift

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userLabel: UILabel!
var cliente = Cliente()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nombreCliente:String = cliente.nombre
    let fullNameArr = nombreCliente.components(separatedBy:(" "))
    let nombre    = fullNameArr[2]
    let apellido = fullNameArr[0]
    self.userLabel.text = "Hola, "+nombre.capitalized+" "+apellido.capitalized

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Alguna idea del porque me sale este error?

muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Verifica en tu storyboard o en tu xib que el textField "getText" (o otro textfield o el mismo controller) no tenga un enlace a una propiedad inexistente en tu controlador llamada "getTextId".

Probablemente fue que renombraste la propiedad, es este es el caso ten presente que si renombras un IBOutlet en tu controlador debes eliminar el enlace previo y crear el nuevo, no se actualiza inmediatamente.

P.D: "getText" es un nombre de función no de variable, deberías seguir las reglas de nomenclatura, Un ejemplo sería: `@IBOutlet weak var idTextField: UITextField!` Las variables deben dar una pista de lo que son en sus nombres, si es una vista que termine en View, si es un textfield en Texfield, etc.